# Selecting Distinct row from from table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a main table (AllDocs) and I ran a query which gives me 145 records. And this is good. However, there are some fields (like listid and userid) so I decided to get the titles for listid and userid from 2 different table. Now, my result is 1870. I tried adding `distinct` to `select` and it reduced to 1530. The number of rows should be 145. What am I doing wrong?

```
SELECT DISTINCT AllDocs.SiteId, AllDocs.LeafName, AllDocs.ListId,
                AllDocs.CheckoutUserId, AllDocs.CheckoutDate,
                UserInfo.tp_Title AS [User Name], UserInfo.tp_Login AS [User ID], 
                UserInfo.tp_Email, AllLists.tp_Title AS [List Name]
FROM AllDocs
LEFT OUTER JOIN UserInfo ON AllDocs.CheckoutUserId = UserInfo.tp_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN AllLists ON AllDocs.ListId = AllLists.tp_ID
WHERE (AllDocs.SiteId = 'E2FF98A7-B719-428D-8C30-856F08989691')
  AND (AllDocs.CheckoutUserId IS NOT NULL)
```

Comment: You have multiple rows in either UserInfo/AllLists or both that match the criteria in your on clause. Look at some of the "dupes" and then check them in the individual tables.

Comment: I see your point. Actually, I just need to distinct the LeafName column from AllDocs.

Comment: When LEFT JOIN, put the right side table's conditions in the ON clause to get true left join behavior. When in WHERE you get inner join result.

Comment: I am not aware of your database structure, but i was wondering why you doing LEFT OUTER JOIN instead of INNER JOIN?

Comment: Before you use `GROUP BY`, `DISTINCT` or ranking functions you should ask yourself why records are duplicated when you join those tables. Normally that happens if you link a main- and a detail-table. But in this case it seems as if you have a document-table which you try to link with the user-table to get the CheckoutUser. The logical reason for multiple records could be that multiple users have checked out this document. Do you want all or only the last?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would make it easier to help you.

Comment: Actually, I added AND (UserInfo.tp_SiteID = 'E2FF98A7-B719-428D-8C30-856F08989691') to where clause and now I have 142 rows. Still missing the 3 rows.

Comment: Here is the scheme details. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj594462(v=office.12).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the group by statement. Additional rows are most likely coming back in the query.

```
SELECT AllDocs.SiteId, AllDocs.LeafName, AllDocs.ListId,
   AllDocs.CheckoutUserId, AllDocs.CheckoutDate,
   UserInfo.tp_Title AS [User Name], UserInfo.tp_Login AS [User ID], 
            UserInfo.tp_Email, AllLists.tp_Title AS [List Name]
FROM AllDocs
LEFT OUTER JOIN UserInfo ON AllDocs.CheckoutUserId = UserInfo.tp_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN AllLists ON AllDocs.ListId = AllLists.tp_ID
WHERE (AllDocs.SiteId = 'E2FF98A7-B719-428D-8C30-856F08989691')
 AND (AllDocs.CheckoutUserId IS NOT NULL)
Group by AllDocs.SiteId, AllDocs.LeafName, AllDocs.ListId,
   AllDocs.CheckoutUserId, AllDocs.CheckoutDate, UserInfo.tp_Title UserInfo.tp_Login,  UserInfo.tp_Email, AllLists.tp_Title
```

Comment: I think this might have done the job. Let me verify.